# How can I click a product dynamically in an e-commerce app with Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I'm currently using Cypress to perform E2E tests in an e-commerce web site. At this point when I click on any product I do it with a "hard coded" way, for example: [See line 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az2MJ.png).

This is how the web elements look like for a product:

[E-Commerce Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTUsS.png)

[Web Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEWES.png)

What I'm trying to do is to send by parameter the name of the product so that way I can pick products dynamically.

Any help will be really appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to use the `siblings` functionality to find the `woocommerce-loop-product__title` class with the appropriate title, and then find the sibling `a` tag to click.

```
cy.get('.woocommerce-loop-product__title')
  .contains('Album')
  .siblings('a')
  .click();
```

You could add this as a custom command for re-usability in your test suite.

Comment: This was very useful, really appreciate your input. I added it as a custom command as you recommended.